# How to check answers to questions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an exercise of Fill in the Blanks in which clicking the word from options div moves it into   the first answer div and so on. However, the code of checking answers in which the background of  right answers divs turn green is not working. Please help me solve the problem. The code I am having problem with is:

```
 if (guess == correct) {
     $('.output').css('background', 'green');
 }
```

The link of jsfiddle is: https: //jsfiddle.net/tarunrathore/xp7dq9ue/8/

Comment: What is `guess` and what is `correct`?  Include the logic in your question rather than forcing people to go to a jsfiddle.  Stack Overflow offers the ability to make onsite [mcve] without involving a third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pull the raw HTML from "guess" you are adding whitespace. " Might" does not equal "Might".

`if(guess.trim() == correct)` fixes your immediate issue but then everything with class `.output` turns green regardless if it is the answer to that question.